# Why is row-level access needed when views can limit a person's access to rows and/or columns?

Tags: view, row-level-security

So I've always in general been confused about what the difference between the security of a vew and of Row Level Security.

so I guess my general question is

Why is row-level access needed when views can limit a person's access to rows and/or columns?

Comment: If you had a specific DBMS product in mind, then please add that as a tag. Not all DBMS actually support RLS and the actual possibilities and implications might differ as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking this question in the context of Microsoft SQL Server since **Row-Level Security** is a feature they offer. While there are similarities between using a View to implement a mock row-level security and using the **Row-Level Security** feature of SQL Server, there are a few differences as well:

1. **Separation of Concerns** - **Row-Level Security** abstracts out the security portion from your entities to allow for cleaner and simpler code.
2. **Manageability** - With **Row-Level Security**, you create a **Policy** entity that **Users** can be added to. That **Policy** leverages a **Function** where you define your logic for the security **Policy**. This eliminates the need for custom **Table(s)** to store your users and their access roles.
3. **Reusability** - You can use the same **Policy** for multiple **Tables** without the need of coding repeated logic.
4. **Flexibility** - You can easily turn the **Policy** ON and OFF for any **Table** by setting the `STATE` of that **Policy**.
5. **Performance** - Generally the custom logic used to emulate security at the Row-Level in **Views** can negatively affect performance if the predicates are too complicated. I've seen great performance improvements by removing this logic from your **View's** predicates and creating an **Inline Table Valued Function** with the same exact logic used in a **Policy** for **Row-Level Security**. (I don't fully know why but by looking at the **Execution Plan** in both scenarios, there is definitely a difference which I think is related to the security logic being abstracted out and applied separately from the predicates in the **View**.)

For more information you can read on Microsoft's [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Row-Level%20Security%20enables%20you,rows%20in%20a%20database%20table.&text=RLS%20helps%20you%20implement%20restrictions,are%20pertinent%20to%20their%20department.) docs.

Comment: This is not only a SQL Server feature. As far as I know, many DBMS offer similar features: Oracle, Postgres, DB2 at least. The details differ of course per product. +1

Comment: @ypercube Fair enough, maybe it was just the vibe OP was giving off. Either way, my answer is mostly abstract enough to apply in other DBMS as well.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it's a mistake to use a view as a security object. Views are a reuse-ability feature there to save you from having to remember and type out a series of joins to get well-normalised data into a more human-readable set.

Using join logic or a where clause in a view is a choice about what makes sense for the data transform you're performing in the view. It is not a technique to keep people from seeing things they shouldn't see.

If you want to allow a user credential to see some of the rows in a table and not others, row level security is the more appropriate choice of implementation.

Comment: I strongly disagree with that. Views can absolutely be used as a security object. You can remove access to the underlying tables completely and thus can even hide certain tables completely. And `with check option` can be used to also prevent inserting rows that shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name certainly you can. My assertion is that you shouldn’t. An extended discussion on the whys and hows of it is probably better suited for [chat] rather than comments, though :)